# Need a Firefox-addon to save a selected text as `.txt` file

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, software-rec, firefox-extensions

Need a Firefox-addon to save a selected text as `*.txt` file.

Is there a Firefox plugin for that?

Operating system is Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [**stf**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stf/).

> **stf** lets you save selected text to
>   file.
>
> Works with Firefox 3.0 - 4.0.*

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

[SaveTextToFile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-text-to-file/)

Saves highlighted text to a file in a directory (defaulting to the user's home directory)
After highlighting some text, right-click and select "Save Text to File"
File names have the format "userPreference---.txt"

Features:

- Firefox 19.0 - 30.*
- Optional time/date stamps in saved file
- Optional time/date stamps in saved file name
- Optional dotted line separator between saves in a file
- Can save current page URL into saved file
- Preferences dialog can be shown when "Save Text to File" is clicked
- Text is encoded in UTF-8 (Unicode) so all international characters can be stored correctly
- Determines context clicked and only shows "Save to File" menuitem if context is text
- Ability to either append text to existing file or create a new file

Localization:
English (en-US), Chinese (zh-CN), French (fr), German (de), Japanese (ja), Polish (pl) and Spanish (es-ES)

Open source:
Released under GNU GPL v3 license, want to help work on this Firefox extension? Get in touch ..
https://github.com/bobbyrne01/save-text-to-file-addon/